# Topological vector spaces over different topological fields

Tags: reference-request, topological-vector-spaces

Most books about topological vector spaces talk only about those that are over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ with their usual topologies. I'm curious about the theory of such spaces in more general over other topological fields (ie over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ with non-euclidean topologies or over other fields altogether). What are some references on this topic?

Comment: Maybe it is a situation like [the inner product space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4497717/conjugate-symmetry-in-general-inner-product-space)

Comment: $p$-adic numbers would be an interesting example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some classic texts ...

*Narici, Lawrence; Beckenstein, Edward*, Banach algebras over valued fields, Approximation theory and functional analysis, Proc. int. Symp., Campinas 1977, Math. Stud., North-Holland 35, 333-342 (1979). [ZBL0397.46071](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0397.46071).

*Narici, L.; Beckenstein, E.; Bachman, G.*, Functional analysis and valuation theory, Pure and Applied Mathematics 5. New York: Marcel Dekker VI, 192 p. (1971). [ZBL0218.46004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0218.46004).

*Alling, Norman L.*, [**Fundamentals of analysis over surreal numbers fields**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1216/RMJ-1989-19-3-565), Rocky Mt. J. Math. 19, No. 3, 565-573 (1989). [ZBL0709.12001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0709.12001).